# How to add custome SQL file in laravel migration?

Tags: laravel

I have a SQL file for creating `cities` table and insert 4 thousand records,

how can i create a migration in laravel to import that sql, or use it;

that sql is for specific country and i need to have that table in mysql database.
the important part is to insert all those records in database.
my sql file is below (its  only 31 provinces part ) :

```
CREATE TABLE `ostan` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `amar_code` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `name_txt` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `ostan`
--


/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `ostan` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `ostan` VALUES (1,'آذربایجان شرقی','3');
INSERT INTO `ostan` VALUES (2,'آذربایجان غربی','4');
INSERT INTO `ostan` VALUES (3,'اردبیل','24');
INSERT INTO `ostan` VALUES (4,'اصفهان','10');
INSERT INTO `ostan` VALUES (5,'البرز','30');
INSERT INTO `ostan` VALUES (6,'ایلام','16');
INSERT INTO `ostan` VALUES (7,'بوشهر','18');
INSERT INTO `ostan` VALUES (8,'تهران','23');
INSERT INTO `ostan` VALUES (9,'چهارمحال وبختیاری','14');
INSERT INTO `ostan` VALUES (10,'خراسان جنوبی','29');
INSERT INTO `ostan` VALUES (11,'خراسان رضوی','9');
INSERT INTO `ostan` VALUES (12,'خراسان شمالی','28');
INSERT INTO `ostan` VALUES (13,'خوزستان','6');
INSERT INTO `ostan` VALUES (14,'زنجان','19');
INSERT INTO `ostan` VALUES (15,'سمنان','20');
INSERT INTO `ostan` VALUES (16,'سیستان وبلوچستان','11');
INSERT INTO `ostan` VALUES (17,'فارس','7');
INSERT INTO `ostan` VALUES (18,'قزوین','26');
INSERT INTO `ostan` VALUES (19,'قم','25');
INSERT INTO `ostan` VALUES (20,'کردستان','12');
INSERT INTO `ostan` VALUES (21,'کرمان','8');
INSERT INTO `ostan` VALUES (22,'کرمانشاه','5');
INSERT INTO `ostan` VALUES (23,'کهگیلویه وبویراحمد','17');
INSERT INTO `ostan` VALUES (24,'گلستان','27');
INSERT INTO `ostan` VALUES (25,'گیلان','1');
INSERT INTO `ostan` VALUES (26,'لرستان','15');
INSERT INTO `ostan` VALUES (27,'مازندران','2');
INSERT INTO `ostan` VALUES (28,'مرکزی','0');
INSERT INTO `ostan` VALUES (29,'هرمزگان','22');
INSERT INTO `ostan` VALUES (30,'همدان','13');
INSERT INTO `ostan` VALUES (31,'یزد','21');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can import your SQL files in Laravel like this:

```
DB::unprepared(file_get_contents('full/path/to/dump.sql'));
```

But even if you can do this, its likely that you will hit the max execution time, so if you are using laravel write the migration from scratch and import the SQL data directly by hand on your phpMyAdmin or whatever DB manager you use (TablePlus etc.).